# C++ Check if Key Exists using Map within a Map

Tags: c++, c++11, dictionary

I have a map defined as `map<string, map<string,int> > grandMap;` and I need to check if the internal map has a key `term`. If so, count it. Here's what I tried already:

```
auto countOccurrences(string term) -> int
{
    int count = 0;
    for(auto entry : grandMap)
    {
        if(entry->second.find(term)!=entry->second.end())
        {
            count++;
            cout << "counted" << endl;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

But I get the following error(s):

```
415.cpp:50:11: error: base operand of '->' has non-pointer type 'std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, std::map<std::basic_string<char>, int> >'
415.cpp:50:37: error: base operand of '->' has non-pointer type 'std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, std::map<std::basic_string<char>, int> >'
```

...which clearly points to my attempt to get the second of `entry`, which I thought would be an element of the grandMap, but it doesn't seem to work quite how I'd like...

So what is the right way to go about this?

Comment: `entry.second` instead of `entry->second`. Also, take the `term` argument by `const&`, and use `auto const&` in the range-based `for` loop

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense to change it to `entry.second`. However, what does changing to const& do in the case of this code?

Comment: To avoid premature pessimization: you avoid unnecessary copies without changing the design in any sensible way.

Comment: Btw, there is a standard algorithm called `count_if` that you could use :). See also [this C++1y-ish variation](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/607607a43c328b00)

Comment: That's a pretty neat way to do it, I might use that! Also, feel free to post your comments as an answer so I can accept it! :) Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `operator ->` instead of `operator .`:

```
if (entry.second.find(term) != entry.second.end())
//       ^                          ^
```

Also, to avoid premature pessimization (see [this GoTW by Herb Sutter](http://herbsutter.com/2013/05/13/gotw-2-solution-temporary-objects/) for a definition), you should accept the `term` argument by reference to `const`, and you should also use `auto const&` in the range-based `for` loop.

Moreover, the `count_if` standard algorithm seems to be what you are looking for:

```
// Using C++14's return type deduction for regular functions...
auto count(std::string const& term)
{
    return std::count_if(std::begin(grandMap), std::end(grandMap),
        [&] (decltype(grandMap)::value_type const& entry)
    {
        return (entry.second.find("hello") != std::end(entry.second));
    });
}
```

Here is a complete program:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string, int>> grandMap =
    { { "1", { { "hello", 42 }, { "hi", 1337 } } },
      { "2", { { "hello", 42 }, { "hello", 1729 } } }};

auto count(std::string const& term)
{
    return std::count_if(std::begin(grandMap), std::end(grandMap),
        [&] (decltype(grandMap)::value_type const& entry)
    {
        return (entry.second.find("hello") != std::end(entry.second));
    });
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << count("hello");
}
```

And the corresponding [**live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/607607a43c328b00).

Comment: One thing I noticed: If you're still on C++11, simply adding the return type to the count function will fix the error. Like so: `auto count(std::string const& term) -> int`

Comment: @rar: Yep, C++11 only supports return type deduction for single-return-statement lambdas, nothing else

Comment: FWIW, Clang SVN in C++1y mode already supports `auto const& entry`, aka generic lambdas (but alas, that's slightly more recent than the one at Coliru).

Comment: @TemplateRex: That's good news, thank you for mentioning. I did try using generic lambdas on Coliru but that didn't work, so I resorted to a regular lambda.

Comment: In fact, Clang SVN has been C++14 feature complete since Nov 7, 2013 :-)